# Regex, Find any number except for the number preceded by a letter

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to find all numbers except those preceded by English letter

example one: `test123`  I don't want `123` to match.

example two: `another 123`  I want `123` to match.

example three: `try other solutions 123` I want `123` to match.

I tried many and no one get the desired result, last one was

```
let reg = /((?<![a-zA-Z])[0-9]){1,}/g;
```

but it just ignore this first number I want to ignore all

example : `test123` - it ignored `1` but take `23` , the desired result is ignore `123`

I tried this regex but did not work as well

```
let reg = /((?<![a-zA-Z])[0-9]){1,}/g;
```

and the result must ignore all digits number after English letter

Comment: What do you mean with "ignore"? Please provide some examples of input and expected output for them. Does `\b\d+` do what you want?

Comment: I don't get how that last example works. Please clarify. And did you check `\b\d+`?

Comment: @Abrar You already got your answer in trincot's comment.

Comment: @oriberu No, because `\b\d+` won't match `123` in `abc_123`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Sure, but that wasn't exactly asked for in the question.

Comment: @oriberu It is, see the title: "*Find any number except for the number preceded by a letter*". `\b` also stops matching numbers after `_`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Fair enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```js
const reg = /(?<![a-zA-Z\d]|\d\.)\d+(?:\.\d+)?/g;
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VcXJ63/1). *Details*:

- `(?<![a-zA-Z\d]|\d\.)` - a negative lookbehind that fails the match if there is a letter/digit or a digit followed with a dot immediately to the left of the current location
- `\d+(?:\.\d+)?` - one or more digits followed with an optional sequence of a `.` and one or more digits.

JavaScript demo:

```js
const text = "test123\ntest 456\ntest123.5\ntest 456.5";
const reg = /(?<![a-zA-Z\d]|\d\.)\d+(?:\.\d+)?/g;
console.log(text.match(reg)); // => ["456","456.5"]
```

For environments not supporting ECMAScript 2018+ standard:

```js
var text = "test123\ntest 456\ntest123.5\ntest 456.5";
var reg = /([a-zA-Z])?\d+(?:\.\d+)?/g;
var results = [], m;
while(m = reg.exec(text)) {
  if (m[1] === undefined) {
     results.push(m[0]);
   }
}
console.log(results); // => ["456","456.5"]
```

Comment: It works well thank you, I have one extra condition (if the number is float like 2.5 I want it to match also and ignore it if preceded by letter) @Wiktor Stribiżew

Comment: @Abrar See the updated solutions.